# SPHINX - numref works for HTML but not for LaTex

Tags: python-sphinx, pdflatex, pdftex

I am working on a Sphinx project for software documentation, which includes a lot of figures.
I use 'numref' for referring to the pictures. In HTML it works fine. In LaTex I get Fig. ??
There are only a few issues on numref on the web and the answers did not help me.
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I installed the Sphinx environment with sphinx-quickstart.
Relevant lines from my conf.py are:

```
    # Conf.py

    # Automatic numbering
    numfig = True

    # -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

    latex_elements = {
        # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
        #
        'papersize': 'a4paper',

        # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
        #
        'pointsize': '10pt',

        # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
        # 'preamble': '',

        # Latex figure (float) alignment
        # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
        'figure_align': 'H' # disable floating
    }

    # Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
    # (source start file, target name, title,
    #  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).

    latex_documents = [
        (master_doc, 'PDF_Test.tex', 'PDF generation',
         'Niels de Nies', 'manual'),
    ]
```

My source (index.rst) looks like:

```
    #########################
    Sphinx numref Test
    #########################

    My first chapter
    ----------------

    The purpose of this test is to get the numref of figures working in LaTex.

    Section 1
    ~~~~~~~~~
    .. figure:: ../images/hippo.png
        :name: hippo

    :numref:`hippo` Hippopotamus    

    The figure above (:numref:`hippo`) shows an illuminated hippopotamus.

    The 'numref' works fine in HTML, but results in Fig. ?? with LaTex

    Below the alternative way using a label. The results are exactly the same:
    Perfect for HTML, but undefined reference for latexpdf

    .. _fig_hippo:

    .. figure:: ../images/hippo.png
        :name: hippo

    :numref:`fig_hippo` Hippopotamus
```

On the commandline LaTeX shows:

```
    === TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
    Latexmk: Index file 'PDF_Test.idx' was written
    Latexmk: Log file says output to 'PDF_Test.pdf'
    Latexmk: List of undefined refs and citations:
      Reference `index:hippo' on page 1 undefined on input line 111
      Reference `index:hippo' on page 1 undefined on input line 113
    Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of (pdf)latex:
      Latex failed to resolve 2 reference(s)
    Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

In the generated PDF_Test.tex the following lines are giving the trouble:

```
    \hyperref[\detokenize{index:hippo}]{Fig.\@ \ref{\detokenize{index:hippo}}} Hippopotamus

    The figure above (\hyperref[\detokenize{index:hippo}]{Fig.\@ \ref{\detokenize{index:hippo}}}) shows an illuminated hippopotamus.
```

Can anybody please give me a clue how to fix this?

Comment: Please do not paste an image of log files. Paste the actual text.

Comment: Also check the Sphinx issue tracker. It looks like there are a [lot of issues with `numref`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+numref).

Comment: I checked the issue tracker, but there is only one issue that is like mine. But the suggested 'workaround' does not work for me.

Comment: Is there really a `name` option for figures? I think you need a label.

Comment: There is a name option, definitely. I added the alternative way, using a label, at the bottom of index.rst. But the results are the same.

Comment: It appears that a caption is necessary to make it work in LaTeX/PDF. Related bug report: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6914

Comment: Please submit the solution as an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Sorry. I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

It took a lot of time, but finally I found the answer.
The sourcecode should look like this:

```
    .. figure:: ../images/hippo.png
        :name: hippo

        Hippopotamus    

    The figure above (:numref:`hippo`) shows an illuminated hippopotamus.
```

Shows in HTML and PDF like:

[image: Numref working!]

Answer (score 0):

Or, put another way, for :numref: to work properly, the figure *requires* the caption text.  When generating HTML if the caption text is there you see the "Figure 2.1: Hippopotamus" and if you leave it off the HTML :numref: link still works but the caption below the figure is missing. For PDF output, the caption is required.  (If you noticed, you also got a missing reference warning from latexpdf.)